# Переход напрямую по URL во Vue.js не рендерит child-компонент при использовании vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

Структура моего роутера следующая(часть для наглядности):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я кликаю по соответствующей кнопке меню (нав. бар слева на скрине ниже), то переход между компонентами работает правильно и в адресной строке указан верный путь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот если попробовать напрямую перейти по этому URL в адресной строке (тупо выделить и нажать enter, например), то получаю 404 ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это именно в случае с child-компонентами в router. 
Почему так происходит и как это можно вылечить? Переход на страницу по умолчанию не подходит. Необходимо именно перейти по указанному адресу и отрендерить то, что и должно быть по этому URL.

Comment: попробуйте в `children => dashboard` `path` указать `''`

Comment: @overthesanity не помогло

Comment: если в адресной строке прописать `/login` - то все работает? не переходя по ссылке

Comment: @overthesanity да, проблема именно с children.

Comment: Вы можете сделать минимальный пример на stackblitz?

Comment: Раньше не сталкивался с stackblitz. Наверное, займет какое-то время. Постараюсь.

Comment: @overthesanity не получается там такой пример создать..

Comment: я Вам так скажу, это проблема не с `vue-router` или `children`, что Вы используете на бекенде?

Comment: @overthesanity node.js/express
сейчас я лишь смог сделать дефолтный редирект на главную, следуя документации. Но мне нужно было именно рендерить конкретный компонент. Насколько я понял, все дело в том, что при использовании Vue нет SSR.

Comment: Здесь не причем SSR, Вам нужно просто на все гет запросы отдавать `index.html`, `app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('path-to-index.html')))`

Comment: `const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

app.use(history({ verbose: true, index: '/' }));
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});`

Comment: Подключите просто обычный `express` или `koa` без этих велосипедов типа `connect-history-api-fallback` :-)

Comment: Но суть ведь в том, что все равно мы перейдем только на страницу по умолчанию, но не туда, куда на нужно.

Comment: Я так понимаю Вы бежите впереди паровоза, у Вас был опыт работы с библиотеками типа реакт/вью? Вы на каждый гет запрос отдаете `index.html`, в `index.html` есть `script` с `src` на `.js` файл в котором собраны Ваши зависимости `vue, vue-router`, дальше все разруливает сам `vue-router`

Comment: добавил вместо своего варианта Ваш, работает также. Думаю, что на этом можно закрыть вопрос. Спасибо.)

Comment: `children` работает?

Comment: Работает, но идёт накладка компонентов. Маленький баг с самим компонентом я уже поправлю. К вопросу это не относится.

Comment: Хорошо, удачи :-)

Comment: Спасибо, взаимно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется node.js/Express (как в моем случае), то необходимо прописать следующую строку

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }));
```

Answer (score -1):

Может быть вам необходим [Режим HTML5 History](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)?

По умолчанию `vue-router` работает в режиме хэша — он использует хэш URL для симуляции полного URL-адреса, что позволяет избежать перезагрузки страницы при изменении URL.

Comment: Я его и использую.